# Including jquery datatable on angular with plain html template

Tags: angular, typescript, datatables

I have a template that uses bootstrap and HTML5 which was not created for angular, but which I am trying to adapt to angular.

I have the following lines in my `angular.json` file:

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.css",
  "src/assets/fonts/icomoon/icomoon.css",
  "src/assets/vendor/circliful/circliful.css",
  "src/assets/vendor/c3/c3.min.css",
  "src/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "src/assets/css/main.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "src/assets/js/jquery.js",
  "src/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js",
  "src/assets/js/popper.min.js",
  "src/assets/vendor/slimscroll/slimscroll.min.js",
  "src/assets/vendor/slimscroll/custom-scrollbar.js",
  "src/assets/vendor/circliful/circliful.min.js",
  "src/assets/vendor/circliful/circliful.custom.js",
  "src/assets/vendor/peity/peity.min.js",
  "src/assets/vendor/peity/custom-peity.js",
  "src/assets/vendor/d3/d3.min.js",
  "src/assets/vendor/c3/c3.min.js",
  "src/assets/vendor/c3/custom/bar-graph-one.js",
  "src/assets/js/common.js"
]
```

Every `assets` file is from this template. Now, I need to insert a jquery datatable into my `home.component.html`, so I installed the datatables with npm:

```
npm install datatables.net --save
npm install datatables.net-bs4 --save
```

And afterwards I inserted this code in my `home.component.ts` file:

```
import 'datatables.net';
import 'datatables.net-bs4';

declare var $ :any;
...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  //for jquery datatable
  datatable: any;

  constructor(private service: HomeService, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }


  ngOnInit() {
      const table: any = $('#notas-table');
      this.datatable = table.DataTable();
  }
}
```

Now though, after loading the page I got this error:

> ERROR TypeError: table.DataTable is not a function

Looking at `vendor.js` file the datatable is there:

```
/***/ "./node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js":
/*!*************************************************************!*\
  !*** ./node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js ***!
  \*************************************************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
```

I tried to put it in AfterViewInit but I get the same error:

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const table: any = $('#notas-table');
    this.datatable = table.DataTable();
  }
```

Comment: Just a random thought, try with AfterViewInit instead?

Comment: Yeah, i tried . Same error.